# How to avoid unnecessary computations finding maximum independent sets?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, set, graph-theory

I coded an algorithm to find maximal independent sets of a graph. By definition an independent set is "a set S such that every edge of the graph has at least one endpoint not in S and every vertex not in S has at least one neighbor in S"

The graph is an undirected graph as shown below:

Nodes : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
Edges : 1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-7,1-5

And here is my implementation:

```
FindMIS fms= new FindMIS(network);


public class FindMIS {

INetwork network;

public FindMIS(INetwork network) {

    this.network = network;
    ArrayList<INode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    nodes.addAll(network.getNodesList());
    Iterator<INode> iter = nodes.iterator();
    ArrayList<INode> IS = new ArrayList<>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        INode node=iter.next();
        visitNode(node, IS, nodes);

    }


}

private void visitNode(INode node, ArrayList<INode> previousIS, ArrayList<INode>   

previousCandidates) {


    ArrayList<INode> IS=new ArrayList<>();
     IS.addAll(previousIS);
    ArrayList<INode> candidates = new ArrayList<>();

    candidates.addAll(previousCandidates);
    //System.out.println(node);
    ArrayList<INode> neighbor = (ArrayList<INode>) network.getNeighborsof(node);
    for (INode n : previousCandidates) {
        if (neighbor.contains(n)) {
            candidates.remove(n);
        }

    }
    IS.add(node);

    candidates.remove(node);
    Iterator<INode> iter = candidates.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        visitNode(iter.next(), IS, candidates);
    }
    if (candidates.size()==0){
         Iterator<INode> iter2=IS.iterator();
    System.out.print("output:{" );
    while(iter2.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(iter2.next().getid());
    }
        System.out.println("}");
    }




   }
}
```

The output is below:

```
output:{1 3 6 }
output:{1 4 6 }
output:{1 6 3 }
output:{1 6 4 }
output:{2 4 6 }
output:{2 4 7 }
output:{2 5 7 }
output:{2 6 4 }
output:{2 7 4 }
output:{2 7 5 }
output:{3 1 6 }
output:{3 5 7 }
output:{3 6 1 }
output:{3 7 5 }
output:{4 1 6 }
output:{4 2 6 }
output:{4 2 7 }
output:{4 6 1 }
output:{4 6 2 }
output:{4 7 2 }
output:{5 2 7 }
output:{5 3 7 }
output:{5 7 2 }
output:{5 7 3 }
output:{6 1 3 }
output:{6 1 4 }
output:{6 2 4 }
output:{6 3 1 }
output:{6 4 1 }
output:{6 4 2 }
output:{7 2 4 }
output:{7 2 5 }
output:{7 3 5 }
output:{7 4 2 }
output:{7 5 2 }
output:{7 5 3 }

You can realize that there are some redundant sets like {1,3,6} and {1,6,3}. The final result must be:

output:{1 3 6}
output:{1 4 6}
output:{2 4 6}
output:{2 4 7}
output:{2 5 7}
output:{3 5 7}

I am trying to figure out a way to avoid unnecessary computation. 
I appreciate for any idea.
```

UPDATE :1 : After Darryl Gerrow's reply, I changed my visitNode method as follows: It worked. I have still some issues with my algorithm to make it more readable and portable. I will post the final version whenever I finished. Thanks for all community. If anyone have better idea to find maximal independent sets in a graph other than just looking for all nodes, I really appreciate to read about.

```
private void visitNode(INode node, ArrayList<INode> previousIS, ArrayList<INode>    

previousCandidates) {


    ArrayList<INode> IS=new ArrayList<>();
     IS.addAll(previousIS);
    ArrayList<INode> candidates = new ArrayList<>();

    candidates.addAll(previousCandidates);
    //System.out.println(node);
    ArrayList<INode> neighbor = (ArrayList<INode>) network.getNeighborsof(node);
    for (INode n : previousCandidates) {
        if (neighbor.contains(n)) {
            candidates.remove(n);
        }

    }
    IS.add(node);

    candidates.remove(node);


    Iterator<INode> iter = candidates.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
       INode nextnode=iter.next();
       if (node.getid() < nextnode.getid())
        visitNode(nextnode, IS, candidates);
    }
    if (candidates.size()==0){
         Iterator<INode> iter2=IS.iterator();
    System.out.print("output:{" );
    while(iter2.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(iter2.next().getid() +" ");
    }
        System.out.println("}");
    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're doing an n-squared iteration, so that's why you're getting
{1, 3, 6}, {1, 6, 3}, {3, 6, 1}, .... essentially every possible combination of an acceptable set.

I think you need to re-write the iteration so that you only visit larger nodes than the current node.

ie. you would get {1, 3, 6}, but {1, 6, 3} would not be acceptable because 6 > 3.

You may have to drop the Iterator and use the index methods of the ArrayList.